# Arduino microcontroller to create a data logger

Tags: logging, arduino, microcontroller

I have created a data logger using a microcontroller and 3 potentiometers (X,Y,Z).

Next I added a variable recording rate which ranges from about 1.2 Hz up to 50 Hz.

Finally I am looking to add a 'Calibration button' whereby, when the button is pressed, all readings go to zero and start measuring from there. I have had an attempt at creating the 'Calibration button' and failed.
A friend who knows more about these things than me, has told me that I should try to use an interupt function.

See below.

```
float ZPot = 0;
float YPot = 1;
float XPot = 2;
byte SRate = 3;       //  Sample Rate Adjuster
byte Reset = 10;      //  Reset button.

float ZCalibration = 0;
float YCalibration = 0;
float XCalibration = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(XPot, INPUT);
    pinMode(YPot, INPUT);
    pinMode(ZPot, INPUT);
    pinMode(SRate, INPUT);
    pinMode(Reset, INPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    ZPot = (analogRead(0) / 1023.0 * 105.0) - ZCalibration;
    YPot = (analogRead(1) / 1023.0 * 105.0) - YCalibration;
    XPot = (analogRead(2) / 1023.0 * 105.0) - XCalibration;

    SRate = analogRead(3) / 4;
    Reset = digitalRead(10);

    if (Reset == HIGH) {
        ZCalibration = ZPot;
        YCalibration = YPot;
        XCalibration = XPot;
    }

    Serial.print("X Pot [mm] = ");
    Serial.print(XPot    );
    delay(SRate);

    Serial.print("   Y Pot [mm] = ");
    Serial.print(YPot    );
    delay(SRate);

    Serial.print("   Z Pot [mm] = ");
    Serial.println (ZPot  );
    delay(SRate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An interrupt is basically a way that the MCU can run a bit of code whenever some event happens. In your case, we want it to run the calibration whenever a digital I/O pin transitions from high to low, for instance.

Have a look at *[attachInterrupt(interrupt, function, mode)](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt)* for the code portion of it.  Note that not all pins on the MCU can generate interrupts.

In terms of the electronics, the article *[Arduino Tutorial, Arduino inputs](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson5.html)* explains it pretty well. You probably want to have a pull-up resistor on the pin so that it is normally high, and goes to ground when the button is depressed.